# Will MySQL Client Library for glibc2.5 work on Linux box with glibc version < 2.5?

Tags: c++, glibc, mysql

If I want to package my application which uses MySQL C Library (libmysqlclient.so) with the binary which is compiled with glibc2.5 and ship it, Will it work with older linux boxes with linux 2.3 or so installed ?? Or the behaviour is totally indefinite ?

Comment: It will probably not run at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux and glibc are two different things.  In your title you are stating that the glibc version on your server is 2.5 or less.  However, in your question, you are stating that you have Linux 2.3.  In your question you don't actually state what version of glibc is on your Linux server.

You could, in theory, have glibc version 4 on a Linux kernel version.  In reality, glibc typically requires some version of the kernel in order to be installable.  Looking at the release notes for glibc 2.5 it seems that the minimum kernel version is 2.6.0 so it is very unlikely that your server has glibc 2.5 installed.

Either way, the real question is: what version of glibc is on your Linux server.  If your Linux server has an older version than glibc2.5 you will not be able to run anything that has been built against something newer.

So, in summary, no, you will probably not be able to run the MySQL C library.

Now, all that being said, it seems to me very unlikely that you would have a Linux server with Linux 2.3 installed.  Not only is 2.3 quite old (12-13 years by now), it is also a development release of the Linux kernel.  If, in fact, you are saying that your Linux servers have glibc 2.3 then you should check the kernel version.  If the kernel version is at least 2.6.0 (released in 2004) then you might be able to upgrade glibc to 2.5 and thus run the MySQL library.

Comment: I was trying to say that even if it is kernel with glibc 2.3 my application should run. My application is built using glibc2.3 because we want it to be compatible with virtually any old or new linux box. But the problem here is MySQL client Library which is compiled with glibc2.5 . If In some case somebody is using linux box with glibc2.3 ?? That was what I wanted to ask....BTW I read in wiki that glibc are not forward-compatible but I wanted to make sure

Comment: Correct.  If your library depends on the MySQL client library and that library depends on glibc 2.5 then you won't run if glibc 2.3 is on the machine.  You are right, glibc is not forwards compatible.